# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem:

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop children of type object supplied to Provider, expected a single ReactElement.`

I have searched for an answer for sometime now but can't resolve this. My version of react is 15.3.0.

thanks~

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
    import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
    import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

    import reducers from './redux/reducers';
    import Entrance from './components/Entrance.jsx';
    import EntranceNone from './components/EntranceNone.jsx';
    import CreditPoints from './components/CreditPoints.jsx';
    import CreditPrivilege from './components/CreditPrivilege.jsx';
    import CreditPromote from './components/CreditPromote.jsx';

    let reduxDevTool = null;
    let combReducer = { app: reducers, routing: routerReducer };
    let store = createStore(combineReducers(combReducer), applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

    const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store);

    ReactDom.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Route path="/" component={ Entrance }></Route>
                    <Route path="/EntranceNone" component={ EntranceNone }></Route>
                    <Route path="/creditPoints" component={ CreditPoints }></Route>
                    <Route path="/privilege" component={ CreditPrivilege }></Route>
                    <Route path="/promote" component={ CreditPromote }></Route>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );


require('../less/entrance.css');
import { initRootFontSize,originDomin } from '../utils';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../redux/action';
import { hashHistory ,Link } from 'react-router';

class Entrance extends Component { 
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        initRootFontSize();
        this.state = {
            agree:true,
            submitFlag:false
        };
    }

    handleAgreeMent(){
        this.setState({agree:!this.state.agree});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(creditData.isOpenCreditService === "0"){
            this.context.router.push('/');
        }else{
            this.context.router.push('/creditPoints');
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if(this.props.resCode && this.state.submitFlag){
            if(this.props.resCode == "000"){
                this.context.router.push('/creditPoints');
            }else{
                alert(this.props.resMsg);
            }
        }
    }

    handleClick(){
        if(this.state.agree){ 
            this.props.actions.fetchIsOpen();
            this.setState({submitFlag:true}); 
        }
    }

    render () {   
        return(
            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="credit-img"></div>
                <div className="credit-cont">
                    <p className="credit-cont-up">xxx</p>
                    <p className="credit-cont-down">xxx</p>
                </div>
                <div className="credit-agree"><span className={classNames({icon: true, iconSelected: this.state.agree})} onClick={this.handleAgreeMent.bind(this)}></span><span className="credit-agree-cont">xx<a href={originDomin()+'static.pay.xiaomi.com/mi-credit-points/src/html/agreeMent.html'} className="credit-agree-detail">xxx</a></span></div>
                <div className={classNames({button: true,bottonFalse:this.state.agree,submitFlag:this.state.submitFlag})}  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.state.submitFlag?'x':'xx'}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        resCode: state.app.resCode,
        resMsg: state.app.resMsg,
        dataList: state.app.dataList
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch),
    };
}

Entrance.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Entrance);
```

Comment: Please copy paste your code in a code block and not as an image.

Comment: i'm already paste my code, thanks~

Comment: The offending code is probably in one of your components. At least post `Entrance`

Comment: Why would you use div inside of provider?

Comment: i'm already paste my code, thanks~

Comment: This is not the cause of div